# Vertical Align top on nested span

Tags: html, css

I have a simple problem of vertical align top.

```
<span class="pricing">
<span class="currency>
$
</span>
125
</span
```

What I want to do is to align the $ sign with the number 125 on the top. So, I apply the current CSS

```
.pricing {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
.currency {
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

But when I do this, the $ sign is aligned vertically to the top, but the number is not. It is still vertically aligned to the middle. the result is like this:
[Pricing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es0je.jpg)

I know that there are several workaround for this like positioning it absolute and add some margin and transform to make it look like I want to. But I'm just curious why it works for the currency class and not the pricing class.

Comment: since `span`  are inbricated, you can only set vertical-align to `.currency`, Use `top`, and not `text-top`. As is, it should work anyway. You are not telling everything :)

Comment: please insert full code(html and css) of this element wtf?!